# Why does そっくり（な？） take the な particle?

Tags: particles, adjectives, copula, na-adjectives

I was reading this page: http://helps.ameba.jp/faq/pigg/5301/post_362.html and I found そっくりな, however my dictionary says it's an adverbial noun... and I though those took の as their particle-Then again, I just use の whenever I read noun because I assume it's an apposition.

Comment: My dictionary says, it's a na-adjective, adverb, noun.

Comment: Not really an answer to this question, but [this post](http://nihonshock.com/2013/04/japanese-onomatopoeia/) was very enlightening to me.

Comment: @Tony What dictionary are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You could have guessed it, but そっくり can be used as na-adjective (形容動詞). E.g.

> お父さんにそっくりな顔でびっくりしました。
> His face was so much like his dad's I was shocked.
>
> 昌吉にそっくりな性格だね。
> He's so much like Shoukichi.
>
> 自分(に/と)そっくりなキャラクターを作りました。
> I created a character that looked just like me.
>
> *More examples [at Space ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA&ref=sa)*.

This does happen often with words you've always thought of as pure nouns...

Comment: So what's the difference between words I think are nouns that use な, and words that I think are nouns, and use の?